# Why is this MOSFET KVL to find VDS not right?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, current-source

There was an answer provided for this question I'm working on, but it seems that my answer was wrong. The sticky note has was the "correct answer" is supposed to be, but I don't understand why V-minus on the source is not included in that KVL equation.

[image]

Comment: Is \$V_S\$ the voltage at the source (relative to ground) or is it something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ideal current source dictates the current, but can have any voltage across it. The voltage across it is dictated by external components.
Likewise, an ideal voltage source dictates the voltage, but can have any current flowing through it. The current is dictated by external components (which may be on their turn be controlled by the voltage of said voltage source).

Because \$V^{\_}\$ is below the ideal current source and the voltage drop across an ideal current source can be anything, it is useless to use  \$V^{\_}\$: it will not say anything about \$V_S\$

Comment: Exactly the way I see things and would have written. Nice. +1 of course because I like how I write. ;)

Comment: Thank you! Very well stated, it makes a lot more sense now